# Response from End Point

Tags: python, python-requests

I am looking for Http response requests for 100+ sites and I have placed the all the URL's in server.txt
and I want to append all responses to a list but I am getting error. Can you please help where exactly I am doing wrong.
I have tried below code

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import requests
newlist=[]
with open('server.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        r = requests.get(line)
        p=r.json()
        newlist.append(p)
```

Below is the error I am getting

```
r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py", line 327, in send raise ConnectionError(e)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='google.com%0a', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f2ad565b5d0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

it was not appending to the list

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you paste the exact error message into your post?

Comment: Can you please post the full error you are getting (Edit your post, don't put it in the comments), including the full Traceback message.

Comment: Yeah, I guess probally is a problem with one of your URL's because the structure looks like good. Please, share the error message with us.

Answer (score 1):

`%0a` in your error is a newline character, which is trying to be included in your request. To remove it you can use the `strip()` method.

```
import requests
newlist=[]
with open('server.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        r = requests.get(line.strip())
        p=r.json()
        newlist.append(p)
```

EDIT: Given the error in your comment, you are trying to access a site that does not return a JSON. For example if you do:

```
r=requests.get("https://www.google.com")
r.json()
```

You will get an error as https://www.google.com is not a JSON. However if instead you do:

```
r=requests.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1')
r.json()
```

You get `{'userId': 1, 'id': 1, 'title': 'delectus aut autem', 'completed': False}` as that page does return valid JSON. If you have a mixture of valid JSON pages and not valid JSON pages in your `server.txt` file you can use `try` and `except`:

```
import requests
newlist=[]
with open('server.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        r = requests.get(line.strip())
        try:
            p=r.json()
            newlist.append(p)
        except:
            print("INVALID JSON FOR WEBSITE: {}".format(line.strip()))
```

Comment: File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/models.py", line 651, in json
    return json.loads(self.text or self.content, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/dist-packages/simplejson/__init__.py", line 505, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)

Comment: @satya You are trying to access a JSON from a site that does not return JSON, I have edited my answer to explain this in more detail

Comment: Thanks for your help .

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not your code, but you reach the limit of requests that you could do.

Comment: But right now i am verifying one URL still facing the error

Answer (score 0):

For iterating through all lines like a list, you need to call .readlines() on your file-like object (in your case f).

(See documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/apiref.html?highlight=textfile#distutils.text_file.TextFile.readlines)

For your code, this means trying to replace:

```
for line in f:
```

with

```
for line in f.readlines():
```

Comment: Uh! I see your error just now. So I will go with @Michel Guimarães on that...